# input fields are disabled at login in localhost

Tags: php, drupal-6, phpmyadmin, mozilla

I try to login via localhost on my Drupal site. What it's difficult to see (without an image), is that the 'text input fields' for user and password and also the button 'loggin' are dissabled (discovered when using Firebug (see code => input field gebruikersnaam).

What I know is that Mozilla ask after a software security appliance, but in this case Mozilla gives me nothing? => I don't know it may be something to do with.

```
<input type="text" class="form-text required" disabled="disabled" value="" size="15" id="edit-name" name="name" maxlength="60">
```

Extra information: I'm using firefox Mozilla: 3.6.17.

Comment: More information could be useful. Is this a clean Drupal install? If not, what has changed recently that _might_ have caused this (added new module, wrote some custom code, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug simply right click on the disabled attribute and delete it.

Now you can submit your form

Comment: check for new plugins/modules you installed recently, or the settings maybe something was changed